# Access db creating problems

Tags: c#

I have created a windows application with access on its backend. the problem is that when I installed it it shows operation must use updateable query when i try to insert or update operation ....After this I changed permission of folder where access database resides.Now it works fine.Now the problems is that on each computer where i install it I need to change write permissions on database folder in program files . Is there any solution for this where I can set permissions for my folder at setup creation time. or any other solution u know.....thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Don't put your database in your program folder.
In the newest operating system like Win7 or Vista this folder is read-only for security reason.

The best place is the folder identified by the enum `SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`.
You get the physical path with:

```
string commonAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Inside this path you should have a dedicated path for your application.

```
string myDataPath = Path.Combine(commonAppData, "MyApplicationDataFolder");
```

This scenario is good only if the application is not used by more than the user who installed the software. If you require a multiuser access to your database then you create by yourself a folder on the local disk or in a network share where each user can reach the database.

Usually the work of placing the database backend on the user machine or in a network share is reserved to the installation tool. Numerous tools exist on the market, free and paid. I don't know which tool you use and I can't suggest one or another. However when you select/use one you should check for the presence of these base functionality:

- Ability to refer to the special folders present in the Windows
  Environment. (MyDocuments, ApplicationData, etc...)
- Ability to create sub-folders in these special folders (MyApplicationData)
- Ability to create network shares or use one already present
- Ability to update your configuration file where you store your
  connection string (string replacing)

If the deployment tool works as expected you don't need to do anything inside your application, you read the connectionstring from your config file and open the database.

Comment: where to find this enum folder....do i need to place database file manually in this folder or I need write some code so that my database file is stored in this folder

Comment: The enum `Environment.SpecialFolder` and its value can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx). For the deployment of your database it depends on how you install your application. If you have an installer then you should find in that tool the functionality required to install a file in specific system folder, if you deploy manually then you have no problem. In each case remember to update also your connection string to point to the correct location.

Comment: I tried this but problem is that it stores my database access file in programdata folder in program files but there also it dont give write permission to data base

Comment: If you have only the current user working on the database then use `Environment.ApplicationData` instead of `Environment.CommonApplicationData`. This folder is read/write for the current user.  Could you tell me what's the return value of `string commonAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);`?

Comment: Do i need to create a special folder at the time of setup creation time if yes which special folder?

Comment: If your app will be used only from the local user then install the database in the ApplicationData (and add a subfolder for your app there) instead of CommonApplicationData. Of course you could choose any other folder in your local machine where the local user has read/write permissions. This is the only requirement. See [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/cumpsd/archive/2004/02/08/69403.aspx) on how to give this permission

Comment: Nothing working  for me . Can you Plz give me stepwise solution for this.................  thanks

Comment: I could only give you general directions on the use of a deplyoment tool that resolves your problem at the installation phase. Look at my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Create a text file with exactly same content below and save the file having extension '.reg'.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\Location2]
"Path"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\ACCWIZ1\\"
"Description"="Access default location: Wizard Databases"
```

Test this registry file with double clicking onthis. it will create anew entry in registry.

Save the reg file with your installer and run it with installer. You can execute this file from c# code also.

[registry_hacks_reg](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Registry/registry_hacks_reg.htm)